# How can I sum every first td in column 1 using jQuery to get the balance in General Ledger concept table?

Tags: jquery

My current table data

| Credit | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 12,000.00 | 12,000.00 |
| 33,000.00 | 33,000.00 |

I am having trouble to get the total of every credit td in balance.
How am I suppose to apply this using jquery?

my current code

```
    var sum = 0;
  
        // Iterate over each table row
        $('table .outstanding_tr').each(function() {
            var value = parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
        
            // Add the value to the sum
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                sum += value;
            }
        
        });
        console.log('Sum:', sum);
```

| Credit | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 12,000.00 | 12,000.00 |
| 33,000.00 | 45,000 |

This is what I want to do

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Show the HTML.

We could do something like this if it is the first cell of each TR with class outstanding_tr

```
const sum = $('table tbody tr.outstanding_tr td:first-child')
  .map(function() { return +this.textContent })
  .get()
  .reduce((a,b) => a+b);
```